# ActionScript: Changing a spark TitleWindow's titlebar color

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, custom-controls, flex-spark

I have a simple doubt. I have made a custom ActionScript mxml component, which is a spark TitleWindow with a text area, which header (titlebar) should display a green background if it finds the word 'success' in its text, or red, if it doesn't.

My problem is that I don't know where to access and modify this property, and the only turnaround I've found is binding the 'chromeColor' of the TitleWindow to depend on a boolean that will change depending on whether I find or not the word 'success'. And this does change the TitleBar background to the color I desire, however, it also changes the scrollbar color, for example, which is a bit nasty. The code for my class is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" 
           title="Output: "
           chromeColor="{success ? ( 0x00ff6b as uint) : ( 0xFF0000 as uint)}"
           close="closeHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        [Bindable]
        public var success:Boolean = false;

        public function setText(text:String):void
        {
            textContainer.text = text;
            if(text.indexOf("SUCCESS")!=-1)
            {
                success=true;
            }
        }

        protected function closeHandler(event:CloseEvent):void
        {
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:TextArea id="textContainer" x="0" y="0"  width="100%" height="100%"
            paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10" 
            borderVisible="false" editable="false" fontFamily="Courier New"/>
</s:TitleWindow>
```

So, thanks for reading, and hope anyone knows the answer :)

Cheers,
pepillo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd solve it with extending standard component and creating custom skin.

My version of component:

```
package
{
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

import spark.components.TextArea;
import spark.components.TitleWindow;

[SkinState("disabledSuccessful")]
[SkinState("disabledWithControlBarSuccessful")]
[SkinState("inactiveSuccessful")]
[SkinState("inactiveWithControlBarSuccessful")]
[SkinState("normalSuccessful")]
[SkinState("normalWithControlBarSuccessful")]
public class SuccessfulTitleWindow extends TitleWindow
{
    public function SuccessfulTitleWindow()
    {
        title = "Output: ";
    }

    [SkinPart(required = "false")]
    public var textContainer:TextArea;

    private var success:Boolean;
    private var textChanged:Boolean;
    private var textValue:String;

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    override protected function commitProperties():void
    {
        super.commitProperties();

        if (textChanged && textContainer)
        {
            textContainer.text = textValue;
            textChanged = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    override protected function getCurrentSkinState():String
    {
        var skinState:String = super.getCurrentSkinState();
        return success ? skinState + "Successful" : skinState;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void
    {
        super.partAdded(partName, instance);
        if (instance == textContainer)
        {
            textChanged = true;
            invalidateProperties();
        }
    }

    public function setText(text:String):void
    {
        if (text == textValue)
            return;
        success = text && text.indexOf("SUCCESS") != -1;
        invalidateSkinState();
        textValue = text;
        textChanged = true;
        invalidateProperties();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    override protected function closeButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        super.closeButton_clickHandler(event);

        PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
    }
}
}
```

The skin (based on standard skin):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" blendMode="normal" mouseEnabled="false"
    minWidth="76" minHeight="76" alpha.disabledGroup="0.5" width="400">
    <fx:Metadata>[HostComponent("SuccessfulTitleWindow")]</fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. 
        For panel, border and title background are skinned, but the content area and title text are not. */
        static private const exclusions:Array = ["background", "titleDisplay", "contentGroup"];

        /**
         * @private
         */  
        override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            if (getStyle("borderVisible") == true)
            {
                border.visible = true;
                background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 1;
                contents.left = contents.top = contents.right = contents.bottom = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                border.visible = false;
                background.left = background.top = background.right = background.bottom = 0;
                contents.left = contents.top = contents.right = contents.bottom = 0;
            }

            dropShadow.visible = getStyle("dropShadowVisible");

            var cr:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");
            var withControls:Boolean = 
                (currentState == "disabledWithControlBar" || 
                 currentState == "normalWithControlBar" ||
                 currentState == "inactiveWithControlBar");

            if (cornerRadius != cr)
            {
                cornerRadius = cr;

                dropShadow.tlRadius = cornerRadius;
                dropShadow.trRadius = cornerRadius;
                dropShadow.blRadius = withControls ? cornerRadius : 0;
                dropShadow.brRadius = withControls ? cornerRadius : 0;

                setPartCornerRadii(topMaskRect, withControls); 
                setPartCornerRadii(border, withControls); 
                setPartCornerRadii(background, withControls);
            }

            if (bottomMaskRect) setPartCornerRadii(bottomMaskRect, withControls); 

            borderStroke.color = getStyle("borderColor");
            borderStroke.alpha = getStyle("borderAlpha");
            backgroundFill.color = getStyle("backgroundColor");
            backgroundFill.alpha = getStyle("backgroundAlpha");

            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }

        /**
         * @private
         */  
        private function setPartCornerRadii(target:Rect, includeBottom:Boolean):void
        {            
            target.topLeftRadiusX = cornerRadius;
            target.topRightRadiusX = cornerRadius;
            target.bottomLeftRadiusX = includeBottom ? cornerRadius : 0;
            target.bottomRightRadiusX = includeBottom ? cornerRadius : 0;
        }

        private var cornerRadius:Number;
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" stateGroups="normalGroup" />
        <s:State name="inactive" stateGroups="inactiveGroup" />
        <s:State name="disabled" stateGroups="disabledGroup" />
        <s:State name="normalWithControlBar" stateGroups="withControls, normalGroup" />
        <s:State name="inactiveWithControlBar" stateGroups="withControls, inactiveGroup" />
        <s:State name="disabledWithControlBar" stateGroups="withControls, disabledGroup" />
        <s:State name="normalSuccessful" stateGroups="successfulGroup, normalGroup" />
        <s:State name="inactiveSuccessful" stateGroups="inactiveGroup,successfulGroup" />
        <s:State name="disabledSuccessful" stateGroups="successfulGroup,disabledGroup" />
        <s:State name="normalWithControlBarSuccessful" stateGroups="withControls,successfulGroup,normalGroup" />
        <s:State name="inactiveWithControlBarSuccessful" stateGroups="withControls, inactiveGroup, successfulGroup" />
        <s:State name="disabledWithControlBarSuccessful" stateGroups="withControls, successfulGroup, disabledGroup" />
    </s:states>

    <!--- drop shadow can't be hittable so it stays sibling of other graphics @private-->
    <s:RectangularDropShadow id="dropShadow" blurX="20" blurY="20" alpha="0.32" 
                             alpha.inactiveGroup="0.22" distance="11"  distance.inactiveGroup="7"
                             angle="90" color="0x000000" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0"/>

    <!--- drop shadow can't be hittable so all other graphics go in this group -->
    <s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">

        <!--- top group mask @private-->
        <s:Group left="1" top="1" right="1" bottom="1" id="topGroupMask">
            <!--- @private-->
            <s:Rect id="topMaskRect" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor alpha="0"/>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Group>

        <!--- bottom group mask @private-->
        <s:Group left="1" top="1" right="1" bottom="1" id="bottomGroupMask" 
                 includeIn="withControls">
            <!--- @private-->
            <s:Rect id="bottomMaskRect" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor alpha="0"/>
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Group>

        <!--- layer 1: border @private -->
        <s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" >
            <s:stroke>
                <!--- Defines the TitleWindowSkin class's border stroke. The default value is 1. -->
                <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1" />
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- layer 2: background fill -->
        <!--- Defines the appearance of the TitleWindowSkin class's background. -->
        <s:Rect id="background" left="1" top="1" right="1" bottom="1">
            <s:fill>
                <!--- Defines the TitleWindowSkin class's background fill. The default color is 0xFFFFFF. -->
                <s:SolidColor id="backgroundFill" color="#FFFFFF"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- layer 3: contents -->
        <!--- Contains the vertical stack of title bar content and control bar. -->
        <s:Group left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" id="contents">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" horizontalAlign="justify" />
            </s:layout>
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Group id="topGroup" mask="{topGroupMask}">

                <!--- layer 0: title bar fill @private -->
                <s:Rect id="tbFill" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="1">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:SolidColor color="0xFF0000" color.successfulGroup="0x00ff6b" alpha.inactiveGroup="0.8" />
                    </s:fill>
                </s:Rect>

                <!--- layer 1: title bar highlight @private -->
                <s:Rect id="tbHilite" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
                    <s:stroke>
                        <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xE6E6E6" />
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0.22"/>
                        </s:LinearGradientStroke>
                    </s:stroke>
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0.15" />
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0.15" ratio="0.44"/>
                            <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0" ratio="0.4401"/>
                        </s:LinearGradient>
                    </s:fill>
                </s:Rect>

                <!--- layer 2: title bar divider @private -->
                <s:Rect id="tbDiv" left="0" right="0" height="1" bottom="0">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" alpha="0.75" />
                    </s:fill>
                </s:Rect>

                <!-- layer 3: text -->
                <!--- @copy spark.components.Panel#titleDisplay -->
                <s:Label id="titleDisplay" maxDisplayedLines="1"
                         left="9" right="36" top="1" bottom="0" minHeight="30"
                         verticalAlign="middle" fontWeight="bold" />

                <!-- layer 4: moveArea -->
                <!--- @copy spark.components.TitleWindow#moveArea -->
                <s:Group id="moveArea" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" />

                <!--- @copy spark.components.TitleWindow#closeButton -->
                <s:Button id="closeButton" skinClass="spark.skins.spark.TitleWindowCloseButtonSkin"
                          width="15" height="15" right="7" top="7" />
            </s:Group>

            <!--
                Note: setting the minimum size to 0 here so that changes to the host component's
                size will not be thwarted by this skin part's minimum size.   This is a compromise,
                more about it here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-21143
            -->
            <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableContainer#contentGroup -->
            <s:Group id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
                <s:TextArea id="textContainer" width="100%" height="100%"
                    paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10" 
                    borderVisible="false" editable="false" fontFamily="Courier New"/>
            </s:Group>

            <!--- @private -->
            <s:Group id="bottomGroup" minWidth="0" minHeight="0" 
                     includeIn="withControls">  

                <s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" mask="{bottomGroupMask}">

                    <!-- layer 0: control bar divider line -->
                    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" height="1" alpha="0.22">
                        <s:fill>
                            <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" />
                        </s:fill>
                    </s:Rect>

                    <!-- layer 1: control bar highlight -->
                    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="1" bottom="0">
                        <s:stroke>
                            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" />
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" />
                            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
                        </s:stroke>
                    </s:Rect>

                    <!-- layer 2: control bar fill -->
                    <s:Rect left="1" right="1" top="2" bottom="1">
                        <s:fill>
                            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xEDEDED"/>
                                <s:GradientEntry color="0xCDCDCD"/>
                            </s:LinearGradient>
                        </s:fill>
                    </s:Rect>
                </s:Group>

                <!--- @copy spark.components.Panel#controlBarGroup -->
                <s:Group id="controlBarGroup" left="0" right="0" top="1" bottom="1" minWidth="0" minHeight="0">
                    <s:layout>
                        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="7" paddingBottom="7" gap="10" />
                    </s:layout>
                </s:Group>
            </s:Group>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Group>
</s:SparkSkin>
```

And the simple app to test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:local="*">
    <s:VGroup verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">
        <local:SuccessfulTitleWindow skinClass="SuccessfulTitleWindowSkin" id="window" />
        <s:TextInput change="window.setText(event.currentTarget.text)" />
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Flex 4 Way to do this, would be to create your own custom skin class by copying the code of TitleWindowSkin and to update this to have a green background. You would then tell felx to use your custom skin by adding a skinClass attribute to the TitleWindow tag or by setting the skinClass in a CSS configuration.

Comment: Isn't there really anything quicker/simpler..? :(

Comment: Well ... is this that complicated? The thing is that in Flex4 especially spark the controler and view is realy well separated ... with all benefits and drawbacks.
All you need to do is copy the original and then adjust the lines 184 to 194 to your needs. I know Spark skinning looks difficult and complicated at first, but you will certainly reall start loving it after a while ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If using FlashBuilder, create a new MXML Skin derived from the skin type you want to override (good to use a package named `skins`).  Then create a new ActionScript class and extend the MXML skin.
You will then have full control over the skin, and be able to extend the template if necessary.

[image]

In my case I wanted to override the skin of a `TitleWindow` `[spark.skins.spark.TitleWindowSkin]` (even on a mobile device). Many of the Dialog items (i.e. titlebar) are not skinnable but hard coded. `tbFill` is the ID of the TitleBar. I was able to adjust the Skin code to assign ID property names to the title bar gradient and read Style values to set the colors [in the `updateDisplayList` function].
Then use the name of your custom skin class as the `skinClass` property of the item you are skinning.

```
skinClass="skins.defaultSkin"
```

Overall it's not that difficult to do, using this method. Here is the skin class.

```
package skins
{
    
    public class defaultSkin extends dlgTitleWindowSkin 
    {
        public function defaultSkin()
        {
            super();
            this.setStyle("backgroundColor","#fff2bd");
            this.setStyle("tbFill_GradientStart","#ff5f3b");
            this.setStyle("tbFill_GradientEnd","#ff5f3b ");
        }
    }
}
```

In the derived MXML Skin:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
...
            tbFill_GradientStart.color = getStyle("tbFill_GradientStart");
            tbFill_GradientEnd.color = getStyle("tbFill_GradientEnd");
            
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
}
...
    <!--- layer 0: title bar fill @private -->
    <s:Rect id="tbFill" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="1">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry id="tbFill_GradientStart" color="0xD2D2D2"
                                 color.inactiveGroup="0xEAEAEA"/>
                <s:GradientEntry id="tbFill_GradientEnd" color="0x9A9A9A"
                                 color.inactiveGroup="0xCECECE"/>
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
```